# Git subtree: Use only subrepository instead of whole repository

Tags: git, git-subtree

I have a project that uses some 3rd Party libraries.
So the directory structure is something like:

```
MY_COOL_PROJECT
   3rdParty
      LIB_1
      LIB_2
   Source
      MY_PROJECT
```

The libraries are located in separate repositories. So, if I want to use a git repository for the 3rd Party libraries I can do:

```
git subtree add --prefix 3rdParty/LIB_1 --squash http://My3rdPartyLibs.com/lib1.git master
```

However, inside lib1.git repository there is only one bin folder I need. It contains also  folders such as documentation, examples, etc. How can I only "connect" my repository with lib1/bin folder instead of the whole repository? Is that even possible?

Comment: did you find a solution for the sparse subtree? (the current answer doesn't seem to solve it fully)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally, a git repo is done to be fully cloned/loaded.

You *could* go for a **[sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2861204/6309)** (Git1.7+), but only if you don't intent to do any modification and push those back. See [this example](http://iweinfuld.blogspot.fr/2010/06/note-to-self-how-to-sparsely-check-out.html):

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/si-sandbox/.git/
(master) $ git config core.sparsecheckout true
(master) $ echo message-store/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
(master) $ git remote add origin git://github.com/iwein/Spring-Integration-Sandbox.git
(master) $ git pull origin master
```

---

The [OP user2070238](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2070238/user2070238) [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864887/git-subtree-use-only-subrepository-instead-of-whole-repository/14869316#comment20886689_14869316):

> This worked with a few changes.
>   Because, I use submodule I had to use

```
 echo MY_FOLDER/* >> .git/info/modules/MY_MODULE/sparse-checkout
```

> And for some reason the `MY_FOLDER/` part was not working without `*`

Comment: Thanks, this worked with a few changes.
Because, I use submodule I had to use 

`echo MY_FOLDER/* >> .git/info/modules/MY_MODULE/sparse-checkout`

And for some reason the MY_FOLDER/ part was not working without *

Comment: @user2070238 Excellent. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: The original question was about "git subtree" - this answer covers the sparse checkout instead... at most half of the solution? (maybe not even)

Comment: @inger indeed. subtree wasn't the right tool when it come to selecting only a subfolder of a git repo.

Comment: @VonC right, but I thought the question wasn't just "selecting a subfolder" of repo. To clarify, I have a big.git repo and lib.git repo. The latter has 2 subdirs "./spam"  ad"./stuff". In the big.repo, I'd like to import lib.git using subtree, but only "stuff" not "spam", like this: big/lib/stuff. I thought the OP was asking for this (I may have misunderstood)-anyway, what do you think the best way is for this?  my guess is I'd branch off lib.git clean up there, and subtree-add that branch instead. A separate (automated) job would ensure that cleanup branch is up to date with lib.git's master.

Comment: @inger that would be a good question on its own: I don't know if you can apply a sparse checkout strategy to a subtree merged repo. So branching and cleaning would indeed be more simpler solution.