# There is no "zip download" button to download source in .zip on github

Tags: github, download

I want to download this source file in the zip here:

https://github.com/xdtianyu/android-4.2_r1/tree/master/packages/apps/SoundRecorder

But there is no `Zip Download` button. There is a `Zip Download` button in the root directory of the repository:

https://github.com/xdtianyu/android-4.2_r1

But I don't want to download the whole repository. How can I download that single project (specific subdirectory)?

I read this topic but still, I can't Download source as the zip file:

[Download single files from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604663/github-download-single-files)

[How to download source in ZIP format from GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751227/how-to-download-source-in-zip-format-from-github)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can't download a subdirectory from GitHub as a zip file.

Some options are to

- download the full zip and manually extract the subdirectory that you want, or
- use `git` with sparse checkouts instead of downloading as a zip file.

  - This approach *does* download the entire repository into the `.git` directory, but your working copy will only contain the files and directories that you want.

For more information on sparse checkouts have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14869316/354577).

Answer (score 27):

Use [**DownGit**](http://downgit.github.io); you can download individual files or directories, and even create download-link for them-

[image]

You can also configure properties of the download-file. See [**here**](https://github.com/MinhasKamal/DownGit#how-to-use) for detailed usage.

---

<sub>**Disclaimer:** I fell into the same problem as the question-asker, could not find any proper solution, so **I created this tool** for my own use, and later made it available for everyone.</sub>

Comment: Thank you. This is an absolutely brilliant tool. And thank you for not charging £60/month, for such a service, which seems to be the norm, nowadays. Much appreciated 